# Design my own footprint or find one?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, footprint

I am designing a PCB based around the STM32H7 MCU, which is a LQFP144 package. I'm designing in Altium and was using the Altium vault to find components.

I noticed my specific MCU isn't on there, but other variations e.g. STM32F7 with a package size LQFP144 are.

Just starting out in PCB design, I'm looking for some advice.

Is it more common for me to just choose the other variation on Altium vault and then adjust the pinout and design my own schematic symbol considering the package type is the same, or is it more common to start designing a footprint from scratch?

I appreciate any advice or tips!

Comment: You need to know how to make your own at least so you can make one when none exists and fix mistakes you find in others you download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More common way to define is subjective. Whatever method you choose, be sure to review thoroughly with respect to recommended PCB foot print from the datasheet of the actual micro controller. We have seen variations in the package dimensions as well as special pads considerations. Apart from adjusting the pinout please verify about the pad dimension compliance. Have it reviewed by a third person.

Answer (score 0):

Start from a good existing one as a template.